# Is there a way to use sqrt when using clang and web assembly target

Tags: clang, webassembly, sqrt

I'm compiling c++ to web assembly using clang --target=wasm32 --no-standard-libraries. Is there a way to convince clang to generate sqrt? It's not finding <math.h> with this target.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already tried to compile without the flag `--no-standard-libraries`? If you remove it, the clang probably will find `math.h` library (because its a standard library).

Comment: Fails to find math.h with or without --no-standard-libraries. I should have mentioned this happens on Mac Os (Big Sur).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `wasm32-unknown-unknown` is a completely barebones targets in Clang, and doesn't have any standard library - that is, no `math.h`, no I/O functions, not even `memcpy`.

However, you can usually get away with using `--target wasm32-wasi` + WASI SDK instead: https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk

It includes the whole standard library, including even functions for interacting with the filesystem via the [WASI standard](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI) in compatible environments.

If your code doesn't depend on filesystem / clock / other I/O, then you can safely use WASI-SDK to get `math.h`, `memcpy`, `malloc` and other standard functions, and the resulting WebAssembly will be compatible with any non-WASI environments as well.

Comment: True, but sqrt is a machine instruction, not quite a library function, on most platforms including web assembly. May be there's an intrinsic somewhere that I could use instead of the regular sqrt?

Comment: Ah yes, if that's all what you want, you can use `__builtin_sqrt` intrinsic which has an equivalent signature.

Comment: Great, that's what I've been looking for.

Comment: Absolutely, but there's no answer pointing to __builtin_sqrt. Other than that answers don't tell me anything I didn't know at the time of asking the question...

Comment: *shrug* The question was "Is there a way to convince clang to generate sqrt? It's not finding <math.h> with this target.", given answer reliably convinces clang to generate sqrt and has math.h. But sure, up to you :)